# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to wrap words in spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a piece of code

```
// separate pargraph words by spans
$layer.find('p').each(function(){
    var spanned = $(this).html().split(" ").map(function(w){ return '<span class="word">' + w + '</span>'; }).join(" ");
    $(this).html(spanned);
});
```

which attempts to wrap words (defined as anything separated by a space) inside `<span class="word">` and `</span>` but something is wrong because it's ending up like

[image]

all nested and stuff. So where is the flaw in what I'm doing?

Comment: [You might want to take a look at Lettering.js - it's short and the source is easy to understand, and it does what you're trying to do.](http://letteringjs.com/)

Comment: Can you show us what your original HTML looks like?

Comment: You're probably having problems because you're fetching the HTML content, which will include tags. You really need to do this by going text node to text node.

Answer (score 3):

It can be clearly seen that `p` tag doesn't contains just text but some HTML tags as well which is creating this issue, so instead of doing `.html()` do `.text()` which will return you the plain text.

```
$layer.find('p').each(function(){
    var spanned = $(this).text().split(" ").map(function(w){ return '<span class="word">' + w + '</span>'; }).join(" ");
    $(this).html(spanned);
});
```

Keep in mind this will remove any tag like `a`or `li` ... (this depends upon your use case) but by seeing your question I don't think you have them.

And probably you want to use `$.trim` too to remove unwanted white spaces.

Comment: This would work somewhat better, but you'd lose any structure, like `<i>` tags, `<a>` anchors, `<button>`, etc.

Comment: @Pointy that depends on the use case, let the OP clarify if it does have some tags which he is using to format the text and whether he wants to keep the formatting like that.

Comment: Yes, I actually have `<br/>` tags in the text and that strips them out

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in chrome,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<p id="something">
    Hello world how is everyone
</p>
<script>
$("#something").each(function(){
    var spanned = $(this).html().split(" ").map(function(w){ return '<span class="word">' + w + '</span>'; }).join(" ");
    $(this).html(spanned);
});
</script>
```

Resulting html:

```
<p id="something"><span class="word">
</span> <span class="word"></span> <span class="word"></span> <span class="word"></span> <span class="word">Hello</span> <span class="word">world</span> <span class="word">how</span> <span class="word">is</span> <span class="word">everyone
</span></p>
```

My guess is

a)you're doing some weird async stuff somewhere,

b)you're getting DOM nodes that already have tags in them

c)all of the above

Comment: Your code only works because your `<p>` tag contains *only* a text node.

Comment: true enough. Honestly I had thought that was the case with OP too, but I included b) since clearly splitting html on " " is gonna pick up tags.
I was more worried about the definition of $layer than anything, since it's not obvious to me what it is and what context the snippet is used in.